# Can a div .slideUp WITHOUT clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have two different divs slide up and down respectively WITHOUT clicking. Right now I am trying to slide up and it is not working. I'm using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cover').hide();
    $('#cover').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
  });
</script>
```

I then have a div `id="cover"` with content inside. The `fadeIn` works, but it does not slide up. Is there a way to do this without a click?

All help would be great!

Comment: You're hiding an element and then trying to animate hiding it again, that won't work. The fade-in should be working though, here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2sRWd/

Comment: `.slideUp()` is a way of hiding an element.  `.slideDown()` is for showing.

Comment: unless it's a fixed/absolute element positioned on the bottom with a height of 0, it's not gonna work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to change the positioning of the div and use css for transition/animations

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Mike Edwards said `slideUp()` is for hiding and `slideDown()` is used for showing. You may want to use `slideDown()` for this, but if you are going to use `slideDown()` and `fadeIn()` simultaneously, I think it can't be done (even using `delay()` or setting the `queue:false`).

I achieved a similar effect with `slideDown()` and `.animate('opacity')`.

```
$('#cover').hide().css({'opacity':0});

$('#cover').slideDown('slow').animate({opacity:1}, {queue:false, duration:'slow'});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/yBegC/)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously make sure JQuery is loaded. (that you're not getting the '$ is not defined' error)
You can use the 'After' trigger to chain actions.

If you're aiming to slideUp and slideDown you can do something like this.

```
    $('#cover').slideUp(300).after(function() { 
        $(this).slideDown(300);
    });
```

To see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/U3LVR/

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different div and two kind of animate, you can use callback in each effect or use promise to ensure all effect have been done.

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1').slideUp(300).promise().done(function() {
       $('#div2').fadeIn(400, function() {
          //your next code here...
       });
    });
  });
</script>
```